# button that works with either click or pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have only been able to get a button to work by creating 2 seperate events:

```
 $('#loginSubmit').click (function ()
 {
            var userName = $('#userName').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: "auth.php",
                                             data:"userName="+userName+"&password="+password,
                                            success: function(result)
                                            {
                                                    //$('#mainBody').html(result);
                                                    window.location.replace('chooseGroup.php');
                                            }
                                    })
 });


 $('input').keypress(function(event)
 {
   if (event.which == 13) {

            var userName = $('#userName').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: "auth.php",
                                            data: "userName="+userName+"&password="+password,
                                            success: function(result)
                                            {
                                                    //$('#mainBody').html(result);
                                                    window.location.replace('chooseGroup.php');
                                            }
                                    })
                    }
    })
    });
```

html:

```
 <div class='Lrow'><input type='button' id='loginSubmit' value='Login'></div>
```

i know there is probably a better way. Id love to hear it. In any event,  in the keypress function  "event" is undefined if i use mozilla browser.  this works fine in chrome. Any thoughts?

Comment: `type="submit"` instead of `type="button"` ?

Comment: Is this actually in a form? Why not handle the `submit` event of a form instead of the `click` of a button?

Comment: @Krishna would submit help to invoke the ajax call?

Comment: That's strange, I've always assumed hitting enter fires the click event, and a fiddle shows it does -> http://jsfiddle.net/cpr27/

Comment: @MillerKoijam - You have to preventDefault first & write the submit handler.

Comment: @adeneo not in all browsers; IIRC IE does something stupid with it.

Comment: @Mathletics - it works perfectly fine in my IE, as it should.

Comment: @adeneo oops, I was talking about submitting a form, not hitting enter on a button which has focus. I'm getting ahead of myself, nevermind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the common code into a function.

```
var mySubmitFunction (event) {
    //the code
}

$('#loginSubmit').on("click", mySubmitFunction );
$('input').keypress(function(event){
    if (event.which == 13) {
        mySubmitFunction(event);
    }
});
```

---

BUT there is a better way without listening to clicks/enter key. The better way is to let the form do what it wants.

Forms will submit on enter when you write it correctly. You just to add a submit button and  an onsubmit event. You cancelling the submission there and make your Ajax call. Set the button type to submit and it should work. Bonus is if JS is disabled, form still submits to the server.

```
$("#YourForm").on("submit", function(event){  /* code here */ });
```

Comment: seems tidier then what i have, which i will use. Thanks.  however, how does this handle the press enter event?

Comment: There you go. Handling the button instead of the form itself is almost always the wrong approach.

Comment: No, I did! My "there you go" was in response to you updating to handle the submit. It accompanied my upvote. Apparently I am a poor communicator today!

Comment: I had too much coffee, new machine, had to try all the new options. So maybe I should read. lol

Comment: Using the submit event is the proper way to do this if it's a form, but it still doesn't explain why two event handlers would be needed, the click handler should fire just fine with the enter key.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in a function Eg: `ajaxSubmit()` then use jquery `on` to call your function

```
function ajaxSubmit(){
    var userName = $('#userName').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "auth.php",
        data: "userName="+userName+"&password="+password,
        success: function(result){
            //$('#mainBody').html(result);
            window.location.replace('chooseGroup.php');
        }
    });
}

$('#loginSubmit').on("click", ajaxSubmit );

$('#loginSubmit').on("click", function(event){
    if (event.which == 13) {
        ajaxSubmit(event);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On method takes one or more params as event name as the following:

```
$('#loginSubmit').on("click keypress", function(event){

  if (event.type == "keypress" ) {
     if(event.which == 13)
     {
        put your code here or call function
     }
  }
 else//click event
  {
        put your code here or call function
  }

});
```